# Google BigQuery Partitione Tables - How to create tables automatically daily?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, partition

The question is how to let Google BigQuery automatically create partitioned tables on the daily base (one day -> one table, etc.)?

I've used the following command in the command line to create the table:

```
bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY testtable1
```

The table1 appeared in the dataset, but how to create tables for every day automatically?

Answer (score 1):

From the [partitioned table documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables), you need to run the command to create the table only once. After that, you specify the partition to which you want to write as the destination table of the query, such as `testtable1$20170919`.